# Packaging DX Project and Getting Error "The Default Workflow User must be set before activating this workflow rule"

Tags: salesforce

I am able to deploy to scratch org using `"features": ["DefaultWorkflowUser"]` in my project-scratch-def.json but I am not able to package it using `sfdx force:package:version:create -p "MyAlias" -k MyPassword -w 10`

The only error I am receiving is `The Default Workflow User must be set before activating this workflow rule` on 5 different workflows.  I do not see anything that I can pull in the manifest to fix this.  How do I overcome this so that I can package it?

Comment: Did you got any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. We need to add config file in package creation commmand like below -

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package <Package_name> -k <Key> -f .\config\project --wait 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following line in your project-scratch-def.json

```
"features": ["DefaultWorkflowUser"]
```

This will set the default workflow user as admin in the scratch org while creating package version. See this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)